# What does "N new apps installed" message do in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, modern-ui, windows-installation

Sometimes, probably after some programs installed, I get the following message in new super windows main menu:

[image]

If I click this down arrow, then the useless list with numerous applications is displayed with no apparent way to see these 4 apps.

What is the sense of this message?

Answer (score 5):

As you suspect, it's to inform you new apps have been installed.

When you look at the Apps list, those apps should be marked with "New".

They'd be more noticeable if/when you sort the list by install date.

[image]

Comment: And hopefully you will never see software that you have absolutely no idea what it is or how it get there, but listed as "NEW".